# How is the equation $P(X_1>X_2) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 P(X_1>X_2 | X_2=x) f_{X_2}(x) dx$ derived?

Tags: probability

In [Probability and uniform distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20841/16625), the following equation is used:

$P(X_1>X_2) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 P(X_1>X_2 | X_2=x) f_{X_2}(x) dx$

How the equation is derived? Base on which definition or theorem?

Comment: It is the Total Probability Theorem for continuos densities

Comment: @sinbadh, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability only talks about Total Probability Theorem for discrete probability distribution. Can you point out any reference for  Total Probability Theorem for continuos densities?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution has references, but the general idea is the given by @angryavian in his answer

Answer (score 1):

It follows from conditioning on $X_2$. In the case when $X_2$ is a discrete random variable, we have

\begin{align}P(X_1>X_2) &= \sum_{x_2} P(X_1 > X_2, X_2=x_2)\\
&= \sum_{x_2} P(X_1>X_2 \mid X_2=x_2) P(X_2=x_2)
\\
&= \sum_{x_2} P(X_1 > x_2) P(X_2=x_2).
\end{align}

When $X$ is a continuous random variable, the idea is the same, but we replace $P(X_2=x_2)$ with the density of $X_2$, and replace the sum with an integral. This gives the expression you wrote in your question. There are some technical issues with doing this, but I think you are at a point where you can overlook that.